# How does a terminal produce accurate colors?

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, theme, terminal-emulator

#### Background

I am using terminals in various settings. Often the color output of programs is not correctly rendered on the screen.

The internet is full of recipes for fixing the colors for specific setups. However, I lack an understanding of the concepts behind these fixes.

#### Question

What concepts do I need to know in order to understand why my terminal coloring might be off?

I am running `vim` and the pager `bat` with different color profiles. All within the same terminal session.

I am using the terminal emulators `foot` and `alacritty` with  Wayland (sway), together with ssh and tmux.

#### Testing color correctness

To test color correctness, I use the pager `bat`:

```
bat --list-themes
```

It spits out colored sample code in 20+ different themes to the terminal.
I then compare the output on different machines & setups

P.S. when I write terminal, I mean terminal or terminal emulator

Comment: You will probably have to focus the question a bit more and give us something to work with. Something like: why does this code `tput setaf 1;echo red;tput setaf 0` print different colors in system1, related hardware1 and system2, related hardware2? There are so many layers between your eyes and the code trying to show the color, no specific answer could cover them all here, in a generic manner.

Comment: Most terminal-based apps work with 16 colors that don't have fixed RGB values, it's up to the terminal emulator and its user preference to set their exact shade, and surely these terminals all offer different defaults. It's possible for an app to use additional 240 colors (resulting in 256 in total) which have pretty much the same RGB values across terminals, and even to specify exact RGB values (for certain terminal emuators), but these aren't used that often. So, for example, a certain `vim` profile most likely says "use the user's preferred shade of red" instead of some specific RGB values.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I have made the question more specific for my configuration. Let's see if it is an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways that a terminal can provide colours: the older, indexed palette, and the newer, true-colour terminal patterns.  The former includes all of the 8-, 16-, and 256-colour modes, which are used in virtually every terminal definition other than the ones ending in `-direct`.  (There are also some 88-colour modes, which were never super popular and are effectively unused these days.)

However, there's no standard definition for the 8- and 16-colour sequences, and while there are customary values for the 256-colour palette, some terminal emulators also behave differently there as well.  Thus, other than assuming that, say, 1 represents red, you can't really assume that any particular colour will come out of the terminal, and in fact, people can and do choose to customize the exact shade for various reasons.  For example, I use a semi-transparent terminal (which ends up resembling a grey colour) and a dark red is illegible, so I prefer using a theme with a lighter shade.

[The Wikipedia article covering ANSI colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) shows the differences per terminal emulator, which demonstrates the substantial variety of shades available across terminal emulators, and all of these are considered correct behaviour.  Note that generally, it's the terminal emulator itself that picks the colours for the main palette (in my case, Alacritty), and all other programs run in that terminal emulator, including ones running over SSH, should use the same values for the indexed palette.

Now, if you're using the 24-bit true colour mode of your terminal, you should get colours that are identical.  Many programs support this mode, but it can be difficult to activate because usually `TERM` is not set to a definition ending in `-direct`, which indicates a terminal type that does true colour.  For example, many terminal emulators default to `xterm-256color` even though they do in fact support true colour, because `xterm-direct` is much newer and much less compatible across systems (e.g., when logging in via SSH).  You may need to set `TERM` yourself in your terminal emulator's configuration or your shell's startup code if you know that your terminal emulator and OS will support it.

Modern versions of Vim do indeed support true colour mode and can use the GUI colours in the terminal if `termguicolors` is enabled (and the `t_8f` and `t_8b` patterns are set, as by the terminal definition).  Many other programs, including Git, also support configuring the colours, which is not only a nice feature to have, but also important for accessibility (e.g., to allow people with certain types of colourblindness to pick appropriate colours).

Additionally, tmux has a feature in which it my accept more colours than it can emit.  For example, if inside a tmux session, I'm using `tmux-direct` with programs emitting true colour output, but I reattach later to the Linux console (which has only 16 colours), then tmux will try to map the colours to the nearest supported shade, which will make things work (which is good) but will result in ugly output (which is bad).  Other than failing, there's not much else that can be done in this case.

Comment: And then there is color managment system and an accurate monitor profile (ICC) and taking into account the type of screen (say TFT vs OLED). It's not just what is being output, but how a human perceives it.